# Allow the user to select only quarter month in jquery datepicker

Tags: javascript, jquery

How to limit Datepicker to allow the user to select only quarter month of the year

The Datepicker must allow the user to only select the quater month in future. Dates in the past must not be allowed.

Eg.if we are in jan then, in this case, quarter month should be enabled (march) and jan and feb should disable.
if we are in mar then in this case quater month should enabled(march) and jan and feb should disable.
if we are in Apr then in this case quater month should enabled(jun) and jan,feb,mar,apr,may should disable.

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $('.datepickerOne').datepicker({
        format: "yyyy-mm",
        viewMode: "months",
        minViewMode: "months",
        autoclose: true,
        startDate: new Date(),
        endDate: '+2y',
    }).on("change", function () {
        $("#testDetailsForm").bootstrapValidator('revalidateField', 'formsubmit_date');
    })
});
```

Comment: @Pedram Not only first quater,every quater. suppose current month is jan then we can select from march to full year but jan and feb should be disable,

Comment: Yeah I noticed later

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $('.datepickerOne').datepicker({
        format: "yyyy-mm",
        viewMode: "months",
        minViewMode: "months",
        autoclose: true,
        minDate:new Date(new Date().setMonth(new Date().getMonth() + 1)),
        maxDate: "+2y"
    }).on("change", function () {
        $("#testDetailsForm").bootstrapValidator('revalidateField', 'formsubmit_date');
    })
});
```

Comment: @sekan,in this case its taking next month also,i mean its taking feb also,jan and feb should be disabled for this quater

Answer (score 0):

so try this. this Code Working as you say

```
    $(document).ready(function () {

var currentTime = new Date();
// First Date Of the month 
var startDateFrom = new Date(currentTime.getFullYear(),currentTime.getMonth(),1);
// Last Date Of the Month 
var startDateTo = new Date(currentTime.getFullYear(),currentTime.getMonth() +2,1);

    $('.datepickerOne').datepicker({
        format: "yyyy-mm",
        viewMode: "months",
        minViewMode: "months",
        autoclose: true,
        minDate:startDateTo,
        maxDate: "+2y"
    }).
    on("change", function () {
        $("#testDetailsForm").bootstrapValidator('revalidateField', 'formsubmit_date');
    })
});
```